# Switching between Actionbar home button icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

By using this code, I'm changing the image of home button of the actionbar to hamburger menu icon

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_menu);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

After adding a new fragment I want this icon to be changed with default back icon of the android. But i couldn't manage to do it.

```
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

All this methods are making the issue more complicated. Is there any easy way to do this? Or should I find the android default back button image and set it as home button indicator?

Update 1:

I'm using Fragments with Activities. So first (default) fragment that came with activity should be able to open the sliding menu. So that's why i'm using hamburger menu icon with them. But if user continue with the flow, secondary fragments should not open the sliding menu. I'm trying to change hamburger menu button with default home as up button in this case because pressing home button should direct user to the first/default fragment.

Update 2:

I couldn't get any satisfying answer for this and change the actionbar icon with the custom home as up button. It turns out that some icons are defined private in android so using the same "default home as up" icon seems impossible (for now at least).

Following link, contains the official actionbar icon pack, which you can download and use in your applications for private android icons. But the weird thing is icons are somehow a little bit bigger than the original private icons.
The image sizes are not different from the original android icons but i guess these icons has less padding and more visible area. In order for you to use them as like originals you need to change mdpi image to hdpi, hdpi image to xhdpi image and xhdpi image to xxhdpi in your application...
https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: You can set the image again: `actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.default_menu);`, you should use your own image as the default ones can vary by version and device.

Comment: Is there any method to just set the default home indicator? For other activities, I'm already using the default home as up icon by not setting any custom icon. By doing in your way, I need to change all home as up icons in all activities.

Comment: Why are you having a hamburger icon without any functionality in the first place? This is bad practice in terms of usability.

Comment: Of course it has a functionality. It opens a drawer menu for the main activities, just like in facebook. But if user makes another action, some fragment is added to the activity and hamburger icon should return to the back button because user can only open drawer menu from the parent activities. I can change these fragments to separate activities but this doesn't make any sense to me. Adding a new activity for every screen is nonsense.

Comment: Then this is a very bad way of doing it. You should be using the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` component for this. Google it.

Comment: I'm using SlidingMenu implementation from jeremyfeinstein because my customer wanted it. What is wrong about that? Actually as far as I understand, It has nothing to do with what i'm using because even ActionBarDrawerToggle has no method for setting default button. And that component is deprecated as well. I'm using toolbar implementation for actionbar. And toolbar is the most recent implementation.

Comment: Ah. I understood you wrong. But why are you changing the HomeAsUpIndicator? Is it going to be clickable?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry if i couldn't make it clear previously..